# Collate lists based on values

Tags: python, list

I have two lists. For example:

```
a = [1,None,0,1,None,None]
b=[1,0,None,None,0,None]
```

`a[i]` and `b[i]` are corresponding values. They will be either be equivalent (eg. where i=0), one will contain a value and the other will be none (eg. i=1) or both will be None (eg. i =5). I wish to collate these lists, to produce a list `c`:

```
c = [1,0,0,1,0,None]
```

Currently I do it like this:

```
def combinePredictions (a,b):
    #Naive method to combine lists. Assumes that the lists either have the same value or no value. Not for production use. Only use for testing.
    i = 0
    c = []
    for each in range(len(a)):
        if a[i] == b[i]:
            c.append(a[i])
        elif a[i] == None:
            c.append(b[i])
        elif b[i] == None:
            c.append(a[i])
        i = i +1
    return c
```

How can I do this more efficiently?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how I would iteratively refactor this code.
You don't need separate values for `i` and `each`. If you're iterating over a range, there's not much point in manually incrementing an index.

```
def combinePredictions (a,b):
    c = []
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if a[i] == b[i]:
            c.append(a[i])
        elif a[i] == None:
            c.append(b[i])
        elif b[i] == None:
            c.append(a[i])
    return c
```

You can reduce the number of conditionals, since the only time you don't append a[i] is when it's None:

```
def combinePredictions (a,b):
    c = []
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if a[i] is None:
            c.append(b[i])
        else:
            c.append(a[i])
    return c
```

You can use `zip` to iterate through two lists in parallel, without having to refer to their indices:

```
def combinePredictions (a,b):
    c = []
    for x,y, in zip(a,b):
        if x is None:
            c.append(y)
        else:
            c.append(x)
    return c
```

This is probably good enough, but if we're interested in minimizing line count (arguably at the expense of readability), let's go a little farther.
You can make that conditional into an expression and inline it inside the `append` call:

```
def combinePredictions (a,b):
    c = []
    for x,y, in zip(a,b):
        c.append(y if x is None else x)
    return c
```

You can make that loop into a list comprehension:

```
def combinePredictions (a,b):
    return [y if x is None else x for x,y in zip(a,b)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a list comprehension:

```
a = [1,None,0,1,None,None]
b = [1,0,None,None,0,None]

print([1 if x == 1 or y == 1 else None if x == None and y == None else 0 for x, y in zip(a, b)])
# [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, None]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1, None, 0, 1, None, None]
b = [1, 0, None, None, 0, None]


zipped = [x if y is None else y for x, y in zip(a, b)]

for i in zipped:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is more efficient, but you can definitely make it more pythonic and readable:

```
y_true = [1, None, 0, None]
y_pred = [1, 0, 0, None]
collated = []

for true, predicted in zip(y_true, y_pred):
    if predicted is None:
        collated.append(true)
    else:
        collated.append(predicted)

print(collated)  # [1, 0, 0, None]
```